# Conditional Data Manipulation Task

Tags: r

Let's say I have a data frame as follows:

```r
df<-data.frame(suggested = c(195, 0, 195, 0, 0, 195, 195),
               index = c(1:7))
```

I also have another dates vector. For examples sake, let's just say its the day of a month:

```r
dates<- c(3, 9, 15)
```

I would like to create a new variable in the data frame called prev_dates in which the three values from the dates vector are placed in the first 3 instances in which suggested != 0 and then all other values for the variable are NA.

I am sure there's a fairly easy way to do this but I need a few hundred more mg of caffeine to figure this one out this morning. Thanks for the help!

Edit for clarification: this is what I'm hoping the df looks like at the end:

```r
df<-data.frame(suggested = c(195, 0, 195, 0, 0, 195, 195),
               index = c(1:7),
               prev_dates= c(3, NA, 9, NA, NA, 15, NA))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possible solution

```r
df<-data.frame(suggested = c(195, 0, 195, 0, 0, 195, 195),
               index = c(1:7))

dates<- c(3, 9, 15)

library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  filter(suggested != 0) %>% 
  slice_head(n = length(dates)) %>% 
  add_column(dates) %>% 
  right_join(df) %>% 
  arrange(index)
#> Joining, by = c("suggested", "index")
#>   suggested index dates
#> 1       195     1     3
#> 2         0     2    NA
#> 3       195     3     9
#> 4         0     4    NA
#> 5         0     5    NA
#> 6       195     6    15
#> 7       195     7    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

**data.table**

```r
library(data.table)

df<-data.frame(suggested = c(195, 0, 195, 0, 0, 195, 195),
               index = c(1:7))

dates<- c(3, 9, 15)

setDT(df)
merge(df, first(df[suggested != 0,  ], n = length(dates))[, dates := dates], all.x = T)[order(index), ]
#>    suggested index dates
#> 1:       195     1     3
#> 2:         0     2    NA
#> 3:       195     3     9
#> 4:         0     4    NA
#> 5:         0     5    NA
#> 6:       195     6    15
#> 7:       195     7    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Quick question regarding this. Let's say that I have a dates vector that has a value other than 3. Would I be able to just place length(dates) in the "n =" argument of slice_head?

Comment: yes, `slice_head(n = length(dates))`. fixed the solution

Comment: The `data.table` version may also be written `setDT(df)[head(which(df$suggested != 0), length(dates)), prev_dates := dates]`, which adds the new column to the original data by reference.

Comment: @Henrik, great solution, i am new to `data.table` in your answer helped me